# Run terminal command on boot using crontab

Tags: shell, centos, cron, node.js, crontab

I have a server and on every boot, I have to enter `npm run dev` on the terminal so
Node.js server starts. How do I use crontab to do it for me on every boot?

I want something like this;

```
@reboot echo "npm run dev"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your crontab by executing the following command:

```
# crontab -e
```

The first time you do this, it will ask you what text editor to use (e.g. nano).

Then add the following line to your crontab:

```
@reboot npm run dev
```

This will execute the command on every boot.

Answer (score 2):

To define a cronjob, you can open up a terminal and type in

```bsh
crontab -e
```

use

```bsh
sudo crontab -e
```

to do this as root user.
This should open up your text editor you have defined as your `$EDITOR`. here you can add your command

```bsh
@reboot npm run dev
```

in the last line

and the file should look something like this

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot npm run dev
```

Once you save and exit it should say crontab installed.